# run a function on a string to check parity and add a final letter

Tags: python

I simply for the life of me cannot get this function to do what I want it to do

```
def fix(Y):
    if (len(Y)% 2)==1:
        if Y[-1]=='Z':
            Y=Y+'Q'
        else:
            Y=Y+'Z'
```

Take string Y and if it has odd length, add Z to the end. If Z is already the last letter, add a Q instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python doesn't pass the argument as a pointer but as a value, this means that any changes you do inside a function are known only to that function. You will have to return the value if you wish to do something with it outside of this 'fix' function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only passing the value of `Y`, not changing it in-place.

So, your function should return the fixed value:

```
def fix(Y):
    if (len(Y)% 2)==1:
        if Y[-1]=='Z':
            Y=Y+'Q'
        else:
            Y=Y+'Z' 
    return Y
```

And after that, you can reassign your fixed value to `Y`:

```
Y = fix(Y) #overwrites the previous value, put the fixed one.
```

Hope this helps!